# Spring boot OAuth2 test secured end-point given 200 status without token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-test

I develop spring boot web application with rest end points with OAuth 2 security. All the end points secure properly with password grant_type at runtime.

But test cases with MockMvc not consider token. It can access secured endpoints without token.

What is the reason for this.

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIENT_ID = "web-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "web-secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60*60;
    static final int REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6*60*60;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
                Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), defaultAccessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(defaultAccessTokenConverter()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(){
        return new JwtTokenStore(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";

    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenServices(createTokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/user/recovery").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices createTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(createTokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore createTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(createJwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter createJwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(new JwtConverter());
        return converter;
    }

    public static class JwtConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter implements JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configure(JwtAccessTokenConverter converter) {
            converter.setAccessTokenConverter(this);
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
            OAuth2Authentication auth = super.extractAuthentication(map);
            auth.setDetails(map); //this will get spring to copy JWT content into Authentication
            return auth;
        }
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/user/recovery").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

**RestControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RestControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).apply(springSecurity())
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        String accessToken = obtainAccessToken("test",
                "test");

        ResultActions result
                = mockMvc.perform(post("/test")
                //.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        System.out.println(result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString());

    }

    private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "password");
        params.add("username", username);
        params.add("password", password);

        String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64("web-client:web-secret".getBytes()));

        ResultActions result
                = mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
                .params(params)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials)
                .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
    }
}
```

**MyRestController.java**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class MyRestController implements MyRestControllerInf {
     @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity test() {
        return new ResponseEntity("test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. Add **security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3** entry to **test/resources/application.properties** file.